# Как удалить элемент из моего двусвязанного списка?

Tags: java, списки

Как создать список самому? В принципе, я написал так, что я могу добавить элемент в список, но как удалить - не представляю, точнее, представляю, что нужно элементу переназначить знание о следующем элементе, но как?

```
public class MyList<Robot> {

    class Node<R> {
        R item;
        Node<R> next;
        Node<R> previous;
        int id;

        Node() {
            item = null;
            next = null;
            previous = null;
        }

        Node(R item, Node<R> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
            id++;
        }

        Node(Node<R> previous, R item, Node<R> next) {
            this.previous = previous;
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
            id++;
        }


        boolean nextEnd() {
            return (item == null && next == null);
        }

        boolean previousEnd() {
            return (previous == null && item == null);
        }
    }

    private Node<Robot> top = new Node<>();

    public void put(Robot item) {
        top = new Node<>(top, item, top);
    }

    public Robot last() {
        Robot result = top.item;
        if (!top.nextEnd())
            top = top.next;
        return result;
    }

    public void remove(Robot item) {
        //TODO
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList<String> list = new MyList<>();

        for (String s1 : "Hack Brain and code".split(" "))
            list.put(s1);

        String s5;

        list.remove("Hack");
        while ((s5 = list.last()) != null)
            System.out.println(s5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тебя чем `LinkedList` не устраивает?

Comment: у меня задание - нужно самому написать список, я написал часть - добавить элемент, а вот как удалить - я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

```
public remove(Node<R> e) {
    e.previous.next = e.next;
    e.next.previous = e.previous;
    e.next=null;
}
```

[Оригинальная реализация](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html) LinkedList.

Comment: а как мне вызвать этот ремув из тестера, что мне передать в параметры?

Comment: @HackBrain Я не знаю что за тестер.

Comment: ну у меня второй класс тестера называется с методом main

Comment: @HackBrain очевидно же, что нужно передавать элемент `Node<R>`

Comment: как мне его из класса тестер передать???

Comment: @HackBrain двусвязный список должен возвращать не `Robot`, а `Node<R>`. Нужно добавить методы `public Node<R>` getFirst()` `public Node<R>` getLast()`. Обход списка для поиска нужного элемента делается в пользовательском коде.

Comment: @HackBrain рекомендую реализовывать интерфейс нужного списка чтобы знать какие методы нужно реализовать.